# I went through surgery and IM nail was placed in my leg, removed fear of infection because the OP site refused to close completely,

Tags: orthopedics, bones, bone-fractures, tibia, swelling

I had an accident over 1 year and 4 months ago and till today the OP site has not completely closed, although while dressing it I have seen some  tiny bone fragments coming out  about 5 times and it is a comminuted fracture of the distal (3rd) tibia. 
There is callus formation at the top side of the fracture although very slow and poor alignment of the bone. There is also some sort of apparent shortening and the affected site is currently swollen, although there have been several wound swab (MCS) that have been cultured, but no infection was detected at various stages. 
I have attached the latest XRay snapshot, My question is why the swelling still?
And why has it not healed to a reasonable extent I am in my very early 30's thanks.[image]

Comment: Here on Health.SE, we can't give personal diagnosis due to site policy and other good reasons explained on [meta]. **Please visit a doctor of your choice and talk to them about this issue**

Comment: I am a doctor. I would never even venture an answer to this question without actually examining you, looking at your records, and looking at the xrays in person.

Comment: Okay I just wanted to find out if it is "normal" or if anyone has had such experiences maybe in their line or work or someone they know. I know this  not where to see a Doctor but I am currently seeing one and this is just for person curiousity.

Comment: I must also say thank you @anongoodnurse